# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element error scraping the Model names using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to scrape data from the URL, but when I use the method `find_elemnts()` I get this error. I am trying to get some data. Here is my code:

```
from  selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

#opening the browser
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/")

#sending a request through the search bar
search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'st')
search.send_keys("dell xps")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

#clicking a desired link by the class name
# driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'sku-title').click()

# paths:
# sku-title #class name for href links
# //*[@id="main-results"]/ol/li[1]  #link class 
# //*[@id="shop-sku-list-item-23022673"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2] class name: sju-value #model
# //*[@id="pricing-price-23825371"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div class name:priceView-hero-price priceView-customer-price #price

links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sku-title')
for link in links:
    # href = link.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="main-results"]/ol/li[1]').text
    model = link.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sku-value').text
    # price = link.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="pricing-price-23825371"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div').text
    print(model)

time.sleep(200)
driver.quit()
```

Expecting the data in a text (price, model and the links)

Comment: Edit your question and remove all unwanted and commented code. Also point out which line of code is giving you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scrape the ***Model*** numbers you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.us-link > img"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.search-input"))).send_keys("dell xps")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='submit search']"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='attribute-title' and text()='Model:']//following::span[1]")))])
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['XPS9320-7523BLK-PUS', 'XPS9520-9195SLV-PUS', 'XPS9320-7585SLV-PUS', 'XPS9520-7171SLV-PUS', 'XPS9520-7294WHT-PUS', 'BBY-K2PKKFX', 'BBY-46J4FFX', 'XPS9720-7218PLT-PUS', 'BBY-W8PYKFX']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: is there a way you can regenerate the same output using the driver.find_elements() method?

Comment: @omarwatad There is. But you may become a victim of race around condition. So I suggested the best approach.